# Как вставить переменную в Django templates (Python)

Tags: javascript, python, django, шаблоны, дата

Что-то я всё совсем уже затупил, всё время с массивами, да с массивами а простую переменную **delta** не получается вставить.
viev:

```
def peers_res2(request, peer) :
    dcster=Tellping.objects.filter(peers=peer)[:240]
    dcster2 = Tellping.objects.filter(peers=5121)[:240]
    delta = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
    return render_to_response('graf2.html',{'dcster':dcster,'dcster2':dcster2,},delta)
```

templates:

```
 {
                    enabled: false
                },
                pointInterval: 12000, // one hour
                pointStart: {{ delta }}
            }
```

html на выходе:

```
 {
                    enabled: false
                },
                pointInterval: 12000, // one hour
                pointStart: (Тут пуста , хотя должна быть дата)
            }
```

мда и сама  переменная то

```
print(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=2))
2016-11-11 12:46:54.794647
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы забыли добавить delta в контекст. Попробуйте так:

```
return render_to_response('graf2.html', {'dcster': dcster, 'dcster2': dcster2, 'delta': delta})
```

Подробнее о render_to_response() тут https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/